# Javascript multi-timers/rooms

Tags: javascript, timer

So I'm attempting to make a timer system and controller that puts out ticks which can be used to synchronize users' videos/music to a timer. The version I have works and I hooked it up backend to work with sockets, however now I want to make a way to create multiple timers so I can create a room system out of it. Any ideas how I would go about that with what I have? This version works in console btw.  Don't worry about the sockets part, I already got that taken care of in my fuller version.

```
var count1 = 0;
var interval;
var videoTime = 20;

function checkTimer() {
if (count1 > videoTime + 3) {
restartPause();

}
}

//reset timer
function restart() {
pause();
count1 = 0; interval = setInterval(function() {console.log(count1); count1++; checkTimer()}, 1000);
}

//pause timer
function pause() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

//play timer
function start() {
  pause();
  interval = setInterval(function() {console.log(count1); count1++;     
 checkTimer()}, 1000);
}

//Restart and Pause, for when the video ends
function restartPause() {
restart();
pause();
}
```

Comment: Just store the timers in an object `var timers = {};`. `start();` should return the interval added, and you can pass that id to `restart()`/`pause()`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean FrankerZ.